# How to do dropdawn container with text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new in flutter.And i dont know all wigets from flutter.How to do dropdawn container with text?When tap or press button container should grou up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@VasyaFromRussia/expanding-text-in-flutter-92736226ace5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work perfectly, check it out.
Check the code below:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String description =
      "Flutter is Google’s mobile UI framework for crafting high-quality native interfaces on iOS and Android in record time. Flutter works with existing code, is used by developers and organizations around the world, and is free and open source.";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new ExpandText(text: description),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  ExpandText({@required this.text});

  @override
  _ExpandTextState createState() => new _ExpandTextState();
}

class _ExpandTextState extends State<ExpandText> {
  String firstHalf;
  String secondHalf;

  bool flag = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.text.length > 50) {
      firstHalf = widget.text.substring(0, 50);
      secondHalf = widget.text.substring(50, widget.text.length);
    } else {
      firstHalf = widget.text;
      secondHalf = "";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
      child: secondHalf.isEmpty
          ? new Text(firstHalf)
          : new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(flag ? (firstHalf + "...") : (firstHalf + secondHalf)),
          new InkWell(
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  flag ? "show more" : "show less",
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                flag = !flag;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image: Collapsed]

[image: Expanded]

I hope this helps.